# Show $\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\left[\left(-\frac{d}{dy}\right)^{k}\frac{\sin Ay}{y}\right]\frac{f(-y)}{\pi}dy=(-1)^{k}f_{A}^{(k)}(0)$

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, analysis

I don't know how to prove the integral below.  Integral I have to use in another integral but to use this I need to prove.

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg[\bigg(-\frac{d}{dy}\bigg)^{k}\frac{\sin Ay}{y}\bigg]\frac{f(-y)}{\pi}dy=(-1)^{k}f_{A}^{(k)}(0)$$

where $$f_{A}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\frac{\sin A(x-y)}{x-y}dy$$

Can anyone help me?

Comment: Looks like integration by parts, repeated $k$ times. (I haven't checked that this works out correctly.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Integrate by parts $k$ times to reexpress the integral as

\begin{align}
&\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg[\bigg(-\frac{d}{dy}\bigg)^{k}\frac{\sin Ay}{y}\bigg]\frac{f(-y)}{\pi}dy
=\frac{(-1)^k}\pi \int_{-\infty}^{\infty} f^{(k)}(-y)\frac{\sin Ay}{y}dy\tag1
\end{align}

and note that
$$f_{A}(x)=\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(y)\frac{\sin A(x-y)}{x-y}dy\overset{x-y=u} =
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f(x-u)\frac{\sin Au }{u}du\
$$
$$f^{(k)}_{A}(x)=
\frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{(k)}(x-u)\frac{\sin Au}{u}du
\overset{x-u=-y} = \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{(k)}(-y)\frac{\sin A(x-y)}{x-y}dy
$$
Then, set $x=0$

$$f^{k}_{A}(0)
= \frac{1}{\pi}\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}f^{k}(-y)\frac{\sin Ay}{y}dy
$$
and plug into (1) to arrive at

$$\int_{-\infty}^{\infty}\bigg[\bigg(-\frac{d}{dy}\bigg)^{k}\frac{\sin Ay}{y}\bigg]\frac{f(-y)}{\pi}dy=(-1)^{k}f_{A}^{(k)}(0)$$